# How to set initial value during laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I'm using Laravel migration to add new column `location` in the table `books`

```php
<?php

class AddNewColumn extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('location')->nullable()->after('description');
        });
    }
}
```

I want to add some predefined `location` value for each record of "book". I get it from another table called "locations". So for each book location is different and it's not a default value.
Is there some way set initial value for the column in the migration?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the link below will be useful for you.

edit: if the default value is supposed to be null, make it nullable instead.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#default-expressions

```
<?php

    class AddNewColumn extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->text('location')->after('description')->default('1');
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I need to set initial value, not default. Initial value is different for each records, default - is the same for all.

Comment: @Hevyweb Sounds like this should be done in a Seeder, not the migration